# Lightning component included in tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages

I'd like to display a "header" for those instances where my Lightning component is not displayed in a tab, but directly on the page.  Is there a way to determine if a Lightning component is being displayed in a tab?

[image]

Comment: What is the difference here between a tab and a page? Is your tab a custom tab that you have created and is the page a record page?

Comment: @JayantDas the tab would be the Standard Lightning component you add to a Lightning page.  Its called "Tabs".

Comment: @JayantDas I added a picture to show what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer you another approach.

Instead of trying to figure out where a component is dropped, think about exposing a [design attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) on your component that will allow users to show or hide the header manually when they manipulate it in the App Builder.

**demoComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="showHeader" type="boolean" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showHeader}">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>
    </aura:if>

    <div>Something else</div>

</aura:component>
```

**demoComponent.design**

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="showHeader" label="Show Header?" default="false"/>
</design:component>
```

The above code will result in `Show Header?` property being available to a user in the Lightning App Builder:

[image]

Comment: I like this approach.  I hadn't used design attributes much, but this makes a lot of sense in this context.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So in layman's term, you want to determine what is the parent of your child component.

No, This is not possible and this should never be possible as this contains a great security risk. Imagine any rogue app exchange application reading the parent's component data(in your case tabs) and doing the malicious operation.

> [The aura framework will never have a way for you to get the parent
>   component. That breaks encapsulation.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97290/how-to-get-parent-lightning-components-attribute-in-child-component)

That being said, why should a component behave differently based on where its dropped? 
The component should expose a few properties which parent can fill in and change behavior if needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying makes sense.  Using the workspaceAPI from within an Aura Lightning component, I can get tabs in the current console.  Would that not be a security risk, as you put it?

Comment: Workspace API allows you to open, close tabs but does not allow you read content. On little subset of funtions which wont posses security risk are allowed